# Error al cargar lista de reproduccion

Tags: javascript, html, api, youtube-api

Hola estoy intentando que me reproduzca una playlis de youtube usando el appi

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });

      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.loadPlaylist({playlist: 'PLn5lEmVWb0R8HHSUZ1v-qOVulU6UMl8_B'});
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

pero me sale esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer error es esto :

```
www-widgetapi.js:100 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://seadoglabs.com').
h.B @ www-widgetapi.js:100
h.F @ www-widgetapi.js:97
setInterval (async)
Pa @ www-widgetapi.js:72
Za @ www-widgetapi.js:98
W @ www-widgetapi.js:81
Y @ www-widgetapi.js:102
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady @ home.html:19
(anonymous) @ www-widgetapi.js:124
(anonymous) @ www-widgetapi.js:124
```

El segundo error es esto:

```
GET https://www.youtube.com/list_ajax?style=json&action_get_templist=1&video_ids=PLn5lEmVWb0R8HHSUZ1v-qOVulU6UMl8_B 400
iF @ base.js:2263
g.hF @ base.js:2247
VQ @ base.js:3158
g.WQ @ base.js:3150
o0 @ base.js:4524
E0 @ base.js:4540
g.h.iP @ base.js:6681
TP.a.K.(anonymous function) @ base.js:3035
g.h.eP @ base.js:6629
UP.a.C.(anonymous function) @ base.js:3039
(anonymous) @ www-embed-player.js:516
h.la @ www-embed-player.js:599
h.Ja @ www-embed-player.js:588
fi.A @ www-embed-player.js:584
```

esta es la url por si desean probar:`http://seadoglabs.com/iq/pru/home.html`

Comment: [Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es-419#Loading_a_Video_Player), seguramente es porque tienes que forzarlo a utilizar https

Comment: @EugeniBejan como lo hago?

Answer (score 0):

Estuve mirando un poco, y añadiendo la propiedad `playerVars`  funciona correctamente.

Te dejo el codigo.

(and video player) will replace this  tag. -->

```
<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
       playerVars : {
                'origin' : 'http://tuDOminio.com',
            },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });

  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.loadPlaylist({playlist: 'PLn5lEmVWb0R8HHSUZ1v-qOVulU6UMl8_B'});
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No me funciono, me sale esto : `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://seadoglabs.com').`

Comment: Es que se daña es cuando carga el segundo video, empieza bien pero al cargar la play list se daña.